# My code isn't picking up on invalid entries and won't multiply, divide or subtract

Tags: bash

My code is running, but I when I try to input non whole numbers it doesn't give me the error message "You must enter two whole numbers" and I am having the same issue with when I input a character other than a,s,m,d it doesn't give me the error message "You must enter the correct operator a or m or d or s". Lastly, when I run my code and I want it to multiply, subtract, or divide the number it only gives me the sum.

```
# !/bin/bash
echo "Please enter the first number: "
read num1
echo "Please enter the second number: "
read num2
echo "Please enter the operator [a] Add, [m] multiply, [d] divide, [s] subtract."
read opr
echo "You must enter the correct operator a or m or d or s"
read a or m or d or s
echo "You must enter two whole numbers"
read whole numbers

a = add
s = subtract
m = multiply
d = divide


if [[ $opr==A ]]; then
          sum=$(($num1 + $num2))
          echo "The sum is $sum."
  elif [[ $opr==S ]]; then
          diff=$(($num1 - $num2))
echo "The difference is $diff"
  elif [[ $opr==M ]]; then
          prod=$(($num1 * $num2))
          echo "The product is $prod"
  elif [[ $opr==D ]]; then
          quot=$(($num1 / $num2))
          echo "The quotient is $quot"
  else
echo "You must enter the correct operator a or m or d or s"
fi
                               
example of what I need my output to be:
Please enter the first number:
2
please enter the second number:
1
You must enter a whole number:
-bash-4.2$ ./finalcal.sh
Please enter the first number:
2
please enter the second number:
4
Please enter the operator [a] Add, [m] multiply, [d] divide, [s] subtract:
d
The quotient is 0 with a whole number remainder or 2.
```

Comment: You need spaces around `==` in the `if` statements. Also, if the user is entering lowercase letters, you need to compare with lowercase -- comparisons are case-sensitive.

Comment: What do you think `read a or m or d or s` and `read whole numbers` do?

Comment: Why do you have `echo "You must enter the correct operator a or m or d or s"` right after you ask for the input? That should only be in the `else` at the end.

Comment: Paste your code into shellcheck.net and fix all the problems it finds.

Comment: You have no code that checks if they entered numbers. What is the condition that should trigger the message about entering two whole numbers?

Comment: Why would you tell the user to enter `'a'` and then check `[[ $opr==A ]]`?? (which should be `[[ $opr == A ]]` if checking for `'A'`)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am still having issue with the non whole numbers. When I input the a non whole number my code should recognize that it isn't a whole number and end the output. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_user_input(){
  local num1
  local num2
  local opr
echo "Please enter the first number: "
read -r num1
verify_number "$num1"
echo "Please enter the second number: "
read -r num2
verify_number "$num2"
echo "Please enter the operator [a] Add, [m] multiply, [d] divide, [s] subtract."
read -r opr
verify_opr "$opr"
sums "$num1" "$num2" "$opr"
}

function sums(){
local num1=$1
local num2=$2
local opr=$3

if [[ $opr == "a" ]]; then
          local sum=$((num1 + num2))
          echo "The sum is $sum."
  elif [[ $opr == "s" ]]; then
          local diff=$((num1 - num2))
echo "The difference is $diff"
  elif [[ $opr == "m" ]]; then
          local prod=$((num1 * num2))
          echo "The product is $prod"
  elif [[ $opr == "d" ]]; then
          local quot=$((num1 / num2))
          echo "The quotient is $quot"
fi
}

function verify_number(){
local num_to_check=$1
local re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $num_to_check =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "error: Not a whole number" >&2; exit 1
fi
}

function verify_opr(){
local opr_to_check=$1
local reg='^[amds]+$'
if ! [[ $opr_to_check =~ $reg ]] ; then
   echo "error: Invalid operator" >&2; exit 1
fi

}

function main() {
get_user_input
}

# Calls function main()
main "$@"
```